# Can remote in over IPv6 but not IPv4 using OpenVPN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, ip

We are using an Asus router with built in openVPN to remotely connect to the local network on which a windows machine runs. We then use Microsoft Remote Desktop to facilitate the connection of remote to local windows machine.

Connecting to the VPN with both IPv6 and IPv4 works. However making the connection from remote machine to local windows machine only works over IPv6 when connected to the vpn.

At first I thought there might be a device on my remote network colliding with the IPv4 of the local machine so I assigned an IPv4 I knew wasn't on my remote to the local windows machine. The issue still persists.

a few things I've tested:

pinging remote to local over IPv6 times out but Microsoft Remote Desktop still connects

pinging remote to local over IPv4 times out and Microsoft Remote Desktop doesn't connect

pinging locally to local works and Microsoft Remote Desktop works as well.

Comment: Can you provide the configuration for your OpenVPN?

Comment: You mention that the IPv4 addresses are not colliding, but you *also* need to make sure it's not possible. For most home routers, the X in `192.168.X.0` needs to be changed in the DHCP settings, so that it doesn't match the remote network you're connecting to the VPN from